# Compute Days, absents and late using SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I compute the total Number of Days, Absents and late using sql statement using these three tables, I'm trying to combined them using JOIN statement in MySQL to get the number of days rendered, number of absents, number of late, but it is not working. The output I desired is like this

```
Fullname  |  SchedDate  |   DateFrom    |   DateTO   |   Days   |   Absents   |   Late
```

The following are my tables

```
Employees

empid | fullname |  logs_id
10001 | Emman    |  000001       
10002 | Paul     |  000002       
10003 | Jose     |  000003       
10004 | Mike     |  000004       
10005 | John     |  000005
```

"scheddate" is the assigned schedule of the employee, while the "DateFrom" and "DateTo" are the schedules of the employee. I added scheddate because employee can have schedules with GraveYard shift. 
    Scheddate

```
empid |  Scheddate  |     DateFrom          |        DateTo      
10001 |  2015-08-01 |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  |    2015-08-01 17:00:00                 
10001 |  2015-08-02 |  2015-08-02 08:00:00  |    2015-08-02 17:00:00                 
10001 |  Day Off    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  |    2015-08-01 17:00:00                  
10001 |  2015-08-04 |  2015-08-04 08:00:00  |    2015-08-04 17:00:00                 
10002 |  2015-08-01 |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  |    2015-08-01 17:00:00                    
10002 |  2015-08-02 |  2015-08-02 08:00:00  |    2015-08-02 17:00:00                   
10002 |  2015-08-03 |  2015-08-03 08:00:00  |    2015-08-03 17:00:00                      
10002 |  2015-08-04 |  2015-08-04 08:00:00  |    2015-08-04 17:00:00                       
10003 |  2015-08-01 |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  |    2015-08-01 17:00:00                       
10003 |  2015-08-02 |  2015-08-02 08:00:00  |    2015-08-02 17:00:00                 
10004 |  2015-08-03 |  2015-08-03 08:00:00  |    2015-08-03 17:00:00                 
10004 |  2015-08-04 |  2015-08-04 08:00:00  |    2015-08-04 17:00:00                   
10004 |  2015-08-05 |  2015-08-05 08:00:00  |    2015-08-05 17:00:00                 
10005 |  2015-08-01 |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  |    2015-08-01 17:00:00                 
10005 |  Day Off    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  |    2015-08-01 17:00:00                     
10005 |  2015-08-02 |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  |    2015-08-01 17:00:00
```

The "type" column represent the login and logout where in "0" is the login and "1" is the logout. "datetime" ofcourse the log of the employee. 
    Logs

```
logs_id   |   type   |  datetime
000001    |     0    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00 
000001    |     1    |  2015-08-01 17:00:00  
000001    |     0    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00 
000001    |     1    |  2015-08-01 17:00:00 
000002    |     0    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00  
000002    |     1    |  2015-08-01 17:00:00 
000002    |     0    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00 
000002    |     1    |  2015-08-01 17:00:00 
000003    |     0    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00 
000003    |     1    |  2015-08-01 17:00:00 
000003    |     0    |  2015-08-01 08:00:00 
000003    |     1    |  2015-08-01 17:00:00
```

This is the SQL I tried so far, but it failed. I'm still a newbie in SQL Join, this is what I have tried so far based on combining all I have read on the net. I hope someone could help me out here.

```
  SELECT e.Fullname, e.fp_id, e.empid s.scheddate, s.datefrom, s.dateto,s.empid,
     COUNT(scheddate) as Day
     SUM(CASE WHEN ((f.datetime between s.datefrom and s.dateto) IS NOT NULL) as Absent,
     SUM(Case /* Something goes here*/) as Late
     FROM employees e 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN schedules s ON e.id = s.empid AND ((date(s.scheddate) between '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-05') OR s.scheddate is NULL) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN logs f ON e.fp_id = f.fp_id AND f.datetime is NULL 
     ORDER BY `Fullname` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters; when posting a question like this please provide a DDL for the tables in question and valid sample data.  Even better would be to include a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).  Also when including the desired results, show the results and not just the query columns.

Having said that, I think there is some confusion between what you say you want and what your expected query results should look like.  Given the dataset result, what do you know?  That Emman was on time one day, absent one day, and late one day.  Not very useful...

```
empid   fullname    scheddate                   datefrom                    dateto                      days    absent  late
10001   Emman       August, 01 2015 00:00:00    August, 01 2015 08:00:00    August, 01 2015 17:00:00    1       1       1
10001   Emman       August, 02 2015 00:00:00    August, 02 2015 08:00:00    August, 02 2015 17:00:00    1       1       1
10001   Emman       August, 04 2015 00:00:00    August, 04 2015 08:00:00    August, 04 2015 17:00:00    1       1       1
```

I would recommend removing the `scheddate`, `datefrom` and `dateto` columns if you actually want a summary or if you include the days to treat the `days`, `absent`, and `late` columns as flags.

Given the uncertainty around the actual need, here is the query if those columns are treated as flags.  It could additionally be simplified to have a 'status' column instead of the three columns that used a single case statement.

If an actual summary is needed you can tweak this query to get the other results.

```
select q.empid,
       q.fullname, 
       q.scheddate, 
       q.datefrom, 
       q.dateto,
    CASE
        WHEN q.timein = q.datefrom THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS days,
    CASE
        WHEN q.timein is null THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS absent,
    CASE
        WHEN q.timein > q.datefrom THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS late
  from
(   
   select e.empid,
          e.fullname, 
          s.scheddate, 
          s.datefrom, 
          s.dateto, 
          (select datetime from logs l where l.logs_id = e.logs_id and l.type = 0 and Date(l.datetime) = Date(s.datefrom) and s.scheddate is not null) as timein, 
          (select datetime from logs l where l.logs_id = e.logs_id and l.type = 1 and Date(l.datetime) = Date(s.dateto) and s.scheddate is not null) as timeout 
     from employees e
left join scheddate s on s.empid = e.empid
    where s.scheddate is not null
) q
```